# Is possible to create a new route with only a action name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I'm tring to create a route with only the action name, look:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "UnderConstruction", // Route name
    "UnderConstruction", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Alert", action = "UnderConstruction"} // Parameter defaults
);
```

And with this i want to access the url like that: http://localhost/UnderConstruction

But when i call this url i got the error "The resource cannot be found.". What am i missing or doing wrong?

Comment: In which controller you have this action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to put this route before your default route otherwise it will be matched to default route first and it will try to look for a controller named UnderConstruction.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "UnderConstruction", // Route name
    "UnderConstruction", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Alert", action = "UnderConstruction"} // Parameter defaults
);

//default route
```